# How to add a icon inside a button that shape oval button

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-button, android-shape

I have created a drawable `button_oval.xml`

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:dither="true"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <corners android:radius="120dp" />

    <solid android:color="#eceef5" />

    <stroke
        android:width="3dp"
        android:color="#29395e" />

    <size
        android:width="300dp"
        android:height="120dp" />

</shape>
```

and then i use it on my layout like this:

```
// I want to add a icon inside this button
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/goToPersonalPage"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_oval"
        android:text="@string/memberButton"
        android:textColor="#29395e"
        android:textSize="18dp" />
```

I want to add an icon inside the `Button`, is it any possible to complete it by changing my `button_oval.xml`?

The final output should look Just like the image below :

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: suggest you to use `ImageButton` instead of `Button`.

Comment: Is there any different between imageButton and Button ?

Comment: suggest use linear layout instead

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to add these lines in your **Button** element-

```
android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" // to set an icon
android:drawablePadding="10dp" // to set the padding of icon from text
android:paddingLeft="20dp"  // to set the padding of the icon and text
```

adjust the values according to your need.

It will look like-

[image]

Comment: happy to help you.. :)

Answer (score 2):

Add this code in your `Button` element

```
 android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/yourIcon"
```

Comment: Thanks your code , it can let the icon inside the button , almost be done , but can i adjust the icon position ?

Comment: I find that `android:drawablePadding="-10dp"` can adjust the distance between icon and text , but there is no way out to adjust the icon position , if i want to let the icon marginLeft may be 5dp.

Comment: add this `android:gravity="left|center_vertical"`

Comment: Hey thanks , i try the code , but it change the text position not the icon.

Comment: Add android:paddingStart="5dp" to your Button

Answer (score 1):

in XML

```
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/button_icon"
android:drawablePadding="2dip"
```

or in Acitvity class

```
yourButton.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.icon, 0, 0, 0);
yourButton.setCompoundDrawablePadding(padding_value);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help , i have fix the problem now.